# PowerShell - Add File Name to list of columns to be imported into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to import a spreadsheet that has a few columns - but I would also like to grab the Excel file's name to be added to the list of columns to be imported into MS SQL Server.

Right now - the code below selects the columns I want from the spreadsheet and imports them into a table.  But what I would like to do is grab the file name and include it into the import into a column named `BatchFileName`.

Eventually I want to modify this to loop through the folder and load any spreadsheet it finds, but to get started I wanted to see if this would be possible first.  I tried adding the variable to the Select-Object but that did not work.  And I don't have any other ideas at the moment.

Is this possible? And if so, how would one accomplish this?

```
$FileDirectory = "C:\QualityReport\"
$FileName = "QualityReport05142021.xlsx"    
$BatchFileName = -JOIN ($FileDirectory,$FileName)    
Write-Host $BatchFileName    
$SQLInstance = "localhost"
$Database = "GenericDB"    
$data = Import-Excel -Path $ImportFile -WorksheetName "Sorted" | Select-Object "IP","Network","DNS","NetBIOS","Tracking Method","OS","IP Status","QID","Title","Vuln Status","Type","Severity","Port","Protocol","FQDN","SSL"    
#Write-Host $data   
Write-DbaDataTable -SqlInstance $SQLInstance -Database $Database -Table "dbo.QualityReport" -InputObject $data -Truncate
```

Comment: If you're manually doing this, why not create a column in the Excel file and avoid the complication? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-the-current-excel-file-name-path-or-worksheet-in-a-cell-186833c6-c899-4912-a14c-240c2eb51e0b

Comment: The end-goal is not a manual process - but to pick up files that are saved on a network drive and perform this operation.

Comment: This should give you an extra push: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/mdhelp/en/set-excelcolumn.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell supports [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) on many cmdlets.

You could change the following line (wrapped for clarity):

```
$data = Import-Excel -Path $ImportFile -WorksheetName "Sorted" `
  | Select-Object "IP","Network","DNS","NetBIOS","Tracking Method","OS","IP Status","QID","Title","Vuln Status","Type","Severity","Port","Protocol","FQDN","SSL"
```

To something like this:

```
$data = Import-Excel -Path $ImportFile -WorksheetName "Sorted" `
  | Select-Object @{Name="BatchFileName";Expression={$ImportFile}},"IP","Network","DNS","NetBIOS","Tracking Method","OS","IP Status","QID","Title","Vuln Status","Type","Severity","Port","Protocol","FQDN","SSL"
```

Comment: I figure that it's a preference to do a backtick so you can have a pipe at the start of the next line.
Figured I'd point out to the OP that the pipe character ( `|` ) can be used as a continuation character e.g.

`[...] -WorksheetName "Sorted" | <new line> Select-Object [...]`